# How to un-publish a DNS-SD service?

Tags: avahi

Suppose I have dynamically published a DNS-SD service using `avahi-publish`, as in

```
avahi-publish -s "My service" _myservic._tcp 1234
```

How can I un-publish it without restarting the Avahi daemon?

I want to make a service discoverable via Avahi/Bonjour, but stop advertising it if I shut the service down.  I don't want to restart the whole Avahi daemon, as I may be advertising other dynamic services that I don't want to stop.

Comment: How have you dynamically published it?

Comment: With `avahi-publish -s "My service" _myservic._tcp 1234`. But I think in testing that, I've found my answer.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears I should have experimented more before asking the question. When you publish a service with `avahi-publish`, the process continues running in the foreground (the man pages don't mention this!)  To un-publish, you terminate the `avahi-publish` process.

Previously, I had been using a static configuration with services files; I hadn't wanted to move to using dynamic configuration before I knew how it was supposed to work.